# Special characters packaging error

Tags: vb.net

I have an issue with a function I got from a website.

```
Private Sub AddToArchive(ByVal zip As Package, ByVal fileToAdd As String)
    Try
        'Replace spaces with an underscore (_) 
        Dim uriFileName As String = fileToAdd.Replace(" ", "_")

        'A Uri always starts with a forward slash "/" 
        Dim zipUri As String = String.Concat("/", _
                    IO.Path.GetFileName(uriFileName))

        Dim partUri As New Uri(zipUri, UriKind.Relative)
        Dim contentType As String = _
                    Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip

        'The PackagePart contains the information: 
        ' Where to extract the file when it's extracted (partUri) 
        ' The type of content stream (MIME type):  (contentType) 
        ' The type of compression:  (CompressionOption.Normal)   
        Dim pkgPart As PackagePart = zip.CreatePart(partUri, contentType, CompressionOption.Normal)

        'Read all of the bytes from the file to add to the zip file 
        Dim bites As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(fileToAdd)

        'Compress and write the bytes to the zip file 
        pkgPart.GetStream().Write(bites, 0, bites.Length)
    Catch ex As Exception
        sendException(computerUserName, "ZIP ITSELF EXCEPTION: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

When I have a file with the following file name: näme.jpg it throws an error.

```
Part URI is not valid per rules defined in the Open Packaging Conventions specification.
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try encoding the `ä` character as `%C3%A4`? I don't think a URI with an unencoded `ä` is valid. (fyi, I used [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) to encoded it).

Comment: Did u rename the näme.jpg  and remove the special characters "ä"

Comment: @user2526236 , how would I do that?